# Android - Scroll/Move the ListView itself

Tags: android, listview, scroll, offset

I have seen some modern Android and iOS applications where there will be an Image at the top of the page that covers the entire width of the screen. Beneath it, there will be a `ListView` that stretches all the way down to the page.

When you start to scroll downwards on the `ListView`, the `ListView` itself starts to move upwards until it hits the top of the screen, i.e. completely covering the top screen.

Examples of apps that do this are: **Google** **Play** **Store**, **Huffington** **Post**, **YouTube**.

I've tried googling this but haven't managed to find an relative source.

Comment: all they have is an empty header the size of the image

Comment: @tyczj And do they then slowly reduce the size of the header as the user scrolls down? I assume?

Comment: there is no reducing anything, the header stays the same, the image is below the listview

Comment: Owww of course. Sorry...I'm with you now. Thanks. I'll try that now and mark the answer if you make one.

Comment: I suppose you could translate the image during scrolling in the header but that seems like extra work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of visual trickery, where it seems as the image and list are one but they are really not.

basically you have a listview with a headerview the same size as the image and below the listview you have your image so as you scroll it appears the listview is scrolling over the image.

The layout would look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView></ImageView>

    <ListView></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The create another layout for the header that is empty with the size of the imageview

You can also Translate the image in the Y direction when the list scrolls but then you have to hold onto the view globally in your class so you can translate using `v.setTranslateY()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header to the listview. You can do it by doing this:

```
final View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.myheader, null);
((ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list)).addHeader(header);
```

Then you can do the scroll effect by doing this:

```
    ((ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list)).setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (v.getChildCount() > 0 && v.getChildAt(0) != null)
                header.setTranslationY(Math.round(-v.getChildAt(0).getTop() * 0.5));
        }
    });
```

Here `header` is the header of the listview