# Slide view on top of other view

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a view where one of the views slides on top of another view when the user scrolls. I've recently noticed that many popular apps employ this technique. The best example comes from the mobile version of the Google Play store. When you view an app's store listing, the top portion of the activity is a view with a picture or video of the app, and the bottom portion slides over the top portion when the user begins to scroll (see screenshots below). Is this available as a library somewhere or is this feature built in-house? I know that SlidingUpPanel (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) does something similar, but based on my somewhat-limited research, their 'sliding view' seems to fling to the top or bottom.

So before I jump into it and try to create my own version of this feature, I just wanted to make sure that someone hasn't already invented the wheel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm doing it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789388/android-scroll-move-the-listview-itself/25789669#25789669

Comment: Keyword you're looking for is "parallax". And yes, this particular has been invented already, in several flavours actually. Have a look at [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) and [Paralloid](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid).

Comment: Cool, I'll check those out. Thanks.

Comment: For the ParallaxScroll is there a way to set the parallaxedHeaderView in XML instead of programmatically? All of his examples set the field programmatically, which can be tedious with more complex layouts.

Comment: You can inflate any layout (regardless of its complexity) with a single line of code. That's what `LayoutInflater` is for. ;) As a side note: you can't set a regular header view for a `ListView` in xml either.

Comment: You can check this lib I made. https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-listview

Answer (score 1):

**[Parallax Scrolling Library](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)** is what you are looking for...

## Implementation:

1. **In Gradle:**

   ```
   compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
   ```
2. **In Layout Xml:**

   ```
   <com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:parallax_factor="1.9"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:background="@drawable/item_background"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="PARALLAXED"
           android:textSize="50sp"
           tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
           android:textSize="26sp"
           android:background="@android:color/white"
           android:padding="5dp"
           tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Please add more info how the library works or sample of usage. Link-only-answers are not encouraged.