# click on image that has a layout above

Tags: android, image, onclick, scrollview

Why can't I click this image ?

I'm trying for a while now but it doesn't work.
The idea is to setup a scrollview with a view pager behing that continues to be clickable but I'm not being able to do so. So I started with this simpler example - and also couldn't be able to do so

**code**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




final ImageView ivView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test);
ivView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View v) 
    {           

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    }
```

**layout file**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:clickable="true"
android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
     />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Can someone please shed me some light onto this?
thanks in advance

Comment: where is the linearLayout1? I can´t see it, You set the scroll view to the left of the linearLayout1

Comment: The image is not clickable, because it's UNDER the ScrollView. You can only touch the LinearLayout and the TextView.

Comment: Yes, I know that I want the scrollview to get above the image while scrolling. Somethingk like parallax but more simple. 

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789388/android-scroll-move-the-listview-itself/25789669#25789669

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll